# Find matches by condition between 2 datasets in SAS

Tags: sas

I'm trying to improve the processing time used via an already existing for-loop in a *.jsl file my classmates and I are using in our programming course using SAS.  My question: is there a PROC or sequence of statements that exist that SAS offers that can replicate a search and match condition?  Or a way to go through unsorted files without going line by line looking for matching condition(s)?

Our current scrip file is below:

```
if( roadNumber_Fuel[n]==roadNumber_TO[m] & 
    fuelDate[n]>=tripStart[m] & fuelDate[n]<=TripEnd[m],
                newtripID[n] = tripID[m];
            );
```

I have 2 sets of data simplified below.

```
DATA1:
ID1     Date1
1      May 1, 2012
2      Jun 4, 2013
3      Aug 5, 2013
..
.
```

&

```
DATA2:
ID2    Date2         Date3       TRIP_ID
1      Jan 1 2012    Feb 1 2012  9876 
2      Sep 5 2013    Nov 3 2013  931 
1      Dec 1 2012    Dec 3 2012  236
3      Mar 9 2013    May 3 2013  390
2      Jun 1 2013    Jun 9 2013  811 
1      Apr 1 2012    May 5 2012  76

...
..
.
```

I need to check a lot of iterations but my goal is to have the code
check:

```
Data1.ID1 = Data2.ID2 AND (Date1 >Date2 and Date1 < Date3)
```

My desired output dataset woudld be

```
ID1     Date1         TRIP_ID
1      May 1, 2012    76
2      Jun 4, 2013    811
```

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: There is a distinct lack of 'question' in the above.  What it reads more like is "please write some code for me", without the "please", or the paycheck we usually get for doing such things.  Do you have a question?

Comment: i added a more general clarified question above.  i wish i was getting paid, just trying to learn in school right now :)

Comment: Okay, that's an improvement, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do range matches in two ways.  First off, you can match using `PROC SQL` if you're familiar with SQL:

```
proc sql;
 create tableC as
  select * from table A
   left join table B
     on A.id=B.id and A.date > B.date1 and A.date < B.date2
  ;
quit;
```

Second, you can create a format. This is usually the faster option if it's possible to do this.  This is tricky when you have IDs, but you can do it.

First, create a new variable, ID+date.  Dates are numbers around 18,000-20,000, so multiply your ID by 100,000 and you're safe.

Second, create a dataset from the range dataset where START=lower date plus id*100,000, END=higher date + id*100,000, FMTNAME=some string that will become the format name (must start with A-Z or _ and have A-Z, _, digits only).  LABEL is the value you want to retrieve (Trip_ID in the above example).

```
data b_fmts; 
 set b;
 start=id*100000+date1;
 end  =id*100000+date2;
 label=value_you_want_out;
 fmtname='MYDATEF';
run;
```

Then use `PROC FORMAT` with CNTLIN=` option to import formats.

```
proc format cntlin=b_fmts;
quit;
```

Make sure your date ranges don't overlap - if they do this will fail.

Then you can use it easily:

```
data a_match;
 set a;
 trip_id=put(id*100000+date,MYDATEF.);
run;
```

Comment: +1 for using a format - haven't seen this done that way before

Comment: Merge, Join, Format, Hash, the four horsemen of the SAS Lookupocalypse.

Comment: option 1 worked great.  i'm going to atempt the second option you presented as it looks extremely unique way to attack this type of problem.  thanks.